# Can I shorthand writing "begin..end" when working with iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, std

How can you avoid writing `smth.begin(), smth.end()` all the time when working with iterators?

If, for example, you have to use `std::reverse` – it will look like this:

```cpp
std::reverse(mystr.begin(), mystr.end());
```

But I think I saw somewhere that people were doing the same thing like this:

```cpp
std::<something>::reverse(mystr);
```

Comment: `<something>` -> `ranges`. Ranges (and the corresponding algorithm overloads) are supported since C++20.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::ranges::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/reverse) from the  `<algorithm>` header.

Therefore, the missing namespace is `ranges`, which requires a compiler that supports [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) or higher.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::ranges::reverse(mystr);
```

---

Also check out the other range algorithms from [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges), as well as the adapters from [`<ranges>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), which might be also interesting to know.

For instance, if `mystr` has only to be viewed in a reverse order, the better suitable, is the [`std::ranges::views::reverse`/ `std::ranges::reverse_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view) adapter.

```
#include <ranges> // std::ranges::views::reverse

auto rev_v1 = std::ranges::views::reverse(mystr);
// or
std::ranges::reverse_view rev_v1{ mystr };
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can use the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) since C++20.

For earlier versions, you can use a preprocessor macro instead, eg:

```
#define BeginEndIters(c) (c).begin(), (c).end()

std::reverse(BeginEndIters(mystr));
```

Or, use your own wrapper, eg:

```
namespace MyNS {
    template<typename Container>
    void reverse(Container &c) {
        std::reverse(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
    }
}

MyNS::reverse(mystr);
```